# How to Pass downstream parameter ( e.g Current build parameter ) to downstream job of Jenkins. How to write Scripted pipeline for the same?

Tags: jenkins

[image]

I have attached a screenshot of the parameter I want to convert.
I can not find the scripted pipeline syntax for aggregate downstream test results.

Comment: Have you tried snippet generator? `https://YourJenkinsRoot/pipeline-syntax`

Comment: No there is no option for the above thing@zett42

Comment: so you want simply pass any parameter to downstream job? or restricted to param in your screenshot?

Comment: I want to pass current build parameter to download stream job which works with freestyle job . How to do that in Scripted pipeline. @Rizwan Javid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us pass below params to downstream jobs:-

```
def build_number_of_build="${BUILD_NUMBER}"
def job_name_of_build="${JOB_NAME}" 

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'node_1'
    }

    stages {
        stage('trigger-downstream-job') {
        steps{
        build job: 'Downstream_Job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'job_name_of_build', value: job_name_of_build ], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'build_number_of_build', value: build_number_of_build ]], wait: false
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Now, how to retrieve it in Downstream_Job?

now you can call  directly  `$job_name_of_build` `$build_number_of_build` any where in Downstream_Job, provided the variable *job_name_of_build, build_number_of_build* are defined
in the `Downstream_Job`, to that they can get value from upstream job.

Comment: Thanks @Rizwan I will have a look and will let you know the update.